# start activity without knowing its class

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, dependencies

Is there a way to start an Activity without knowing its class, for example via an Intent Action?

The background is, I have two Modules, ModuleMain and ModulePushNotification. ModuleMain has a dependency to ModulePushNotification. From ModulePushNotification I want to start an Activity in ModuleMain, but I cannot add a dependency ModulePushNotification -> ModuleMain because this would produce a circular dependency.

Therefore, I cannot start the activity this way:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Main.class));
```

I tried to start the Activity using an Intent Action:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.main.MY_MAIN");
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
startActivity(intent);
```

... with this Manifest in ModuleMain:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.main.MY_MAIN" />
            <category android:name="ANDROID.INTENT.CATEGORY.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

... but this produces the Exception:

```
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.android.main.MY_MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT]
```

Is there a way to start the main activity of the app, without restructuring the project/dependencies?

Comment: try removing this - intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

Comment: I removed the line you suggested, but I still get the same Exception

Comment: check my suggested answer

Comment: what version are you using of Android OS?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this way.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("com.android.main.MY_MAIN");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I tried both, with and without category in the manifest, no success. I use API level 16.

Comment: still having the issue...or fixed?

Comment: I think its a problem with the dependencies, I don't know. As a workaround I now use a BroadcastReceiver to start the app. I someone faces a similar problem I can provide the workaround code. Thanks anyway DroidWorm